# Kubernetes Node disconnected from master

Tags: kubernetes

In our cluster we have a node running mongodb that is in a separate facility then the master node. 
I have noticed if the VPN connecting the master node goes down thus separating the local worker node, that I am unable to locally connect to the mongodb port. 
It seems like the mongodb port 27017 goes away when if the worker node disconnects from the master node. 
It was my understanding that Kubernetes is a orchestration system that configures the different worker nodes.
 So if a worker node disconnects I thought that it would just hold the same configuration keeping the mongodb running with its port on that node. 
Is there a setting to keep the node configured as is that I might be missing? 
In our configuration we have a pod that is running under a deployment which is assigned to a service in which that service is assigned to connect the ports to the IP of the worker node that is in question. 
In the cluster configuration we are using the weaves network CNI.